# pyautogui does not click a specific button

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I want to automate an Android game with the emulation software bluestacks 5.

1. [x] detect image
2. [x] move mouse to image position
3. [-] click image

But the 3rd step does not work in bluestacks... (the button is not clicked)

I tested my code on the Windows desktop Start button, and the start button gets clicked...

```
import pyautogui
import time

buttonBack = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('button_back.png', confidence=0.7)

if buttonBack != None:
    print('back image:', buttonBack)
    pyautogui.moveTo(buttonBack)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(buttonBack) 
else:
    print('BACKBUTTON - NOPE')
```

Comment: you should using keybord og pyautogui